# Google Sheets convert Text String cell into Date + Duration cell

Tags: date, text, google-sheets, duration

I get a csv file which I import into a google sheet.
I want to calculate the difference between two "Date Time" combination fields, which are now Text fields and not "Date Time" fields.
Before May they were proper "Date Time" fields in DD.MM.YYYY 00:00, which Google Sheets could work with to calculate the difference in the duration for me. "Updated - Created = Difference". Now it's a text field with the wrong format and the auto convert or manual setting doesn't work. And I work here with a few hundred data sets. So via hand it's a bit rough work...

The DATEVALUE function doesn't work for me. And it was the only related thing I could find.

```
Created         Updated         Difference
07/May/18 06:54 07/May/18 07:14 #VALUE!
07/May/18 07:19 07/May/18 07:28 
07/May/18 07:02 07/May/18 07:56
```

Example how it should look like (Slash or Dot shouldn't matter):

```
Created         Updated         Difference
07.May.18 06:54 07.May.18 07:14 00:20
07.May.18 07:19 07.May.18 07:28 00:09
07.May.18 07:02 07.May.18 07:56 00:54
```

Error code:

```
Error
Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '07/May/18 07:14' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try another region: File > Spreadsheet Settings... Change locale to the US.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I still get the error: Error
Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '07/May/18 07:14' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: I updated my initial post on that. The proper format in Google sheets is called "Date Time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is actually with the language settings.
When I import the data, I've to set the sheet before to US. Then i can work with it. After that I can switch it back to DE and it automatically converts.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will convert month names into numbers [1-12]:

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1;
  "[A-Za-z]+";
  "" & VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec"); 
 {"Jan"\1;"Feb"\2;"Mar"\3;"Apr"\4;"May"\5;"Jun"\6;
  "Jul"\7;"Aug"\8;"Sep"\9;"Oct"\10;"Nov"\11;"Dec"\12};2;))*1`

A result is a serial number: `43227,2875`.

After conversion, you may count duration.